# Sinatra: Specify order in which routes are searched when using multiple apps?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a classic style Sinatra app, and I am adding a modular app to it with `use MyModularApp`.

This works fine, and routes from both the classic and modular apps are available when I run the classic app.  The problem is that it seems the routes from the modular apps are searched first and only then the are the apps from the classic app searched.  I would like the reverse behavior.  How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sinatra applications can be [used as Rack middleware](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Using%20Sinatra%20as%20Middleware) as well as an application in their own right. With `use MyModularApp` you’re [adding the module into the middleware stack](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Rack%20Middleware), so it will see the request before the main application; this will happen wherever you have the `use` method in your source file.

When acting as middleware, Sinatra apps will forward the request down the stack if no route matches in the current app, and so this is why you see the current behaviour.

One way of getting it to work as you want would be to set up a custome `not_found` handler that calls your modular app:

```
not_found do
  MyModularApp.call(env)
end
```

Now if your main app doesn’t have a route that matches the request the modular app will be called.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Sinatra documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Routes):

> Routes are matched in the order they are defined. The first route that matches the request is invoked.

Comment: That answers the questions of how routes are searched within a given app.  But it doesn't help solve my problem.  And it doesn't seem to matter where I place the `use MyModularApp` statement within the classic app -- the modular app is searched first.

Comment: No it wouldn't, it's irrelevant.